# Mindmapping extension for Chrome

Tags: gratis, chrome, mind-mapping

I am looking for **free** mind mapping (if I can say brain storming ) google-chrome extension.

The extension which I look for, should access all the data when I am offline. Also should connect to its server to store the data.

If you know there is "Quick Note" extension, which you can add your notes when you are offline. When you become online if you register in their site, your information goes to there and store on their server ( or on the  clouds )

So I am looking for extension which has that ability. I mean, save your information on your system or also save that on the clouds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MindMap](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mindmap/gdaeohpmcenmffofpikllphdhlkkocfa)

- integrated with Google Drive ('save on the clouds' ;)
- works offline (auto saves to local drive every minute)
- share mindmap via personal URL
- can use Dropbox/Box if you prefer
- export as image option
- print option
- can add images, hyperlinks, notes, etc...
- can change colors of anything

[image]

[image]

Comment: Plenty of negative reviews, though.